# How to block a particular resource from loading in webview

Tags: android, webkit, webview

I've searched a lot for this but did not find any answers. I am developing an android app in which at some point, a webview is displayed which shows you a webpage. But I am really worried about a small advertisement on the web view which shows porn content. Is there any way I can block that from loading on the webpage? Every resource passes the `onLoadingRecource()` method...Is this the place where i can find a solution? I really need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Since API 11, there's [WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), here you can catch loading of embedded objects (images, etc) and replace it with your own image.
For example:

```
WebResourceResponse wr = new WebResourceResponse("", "", new FileInputStream("/sdcard/aaa.jpg"));
return wr;
```

You must detect yourself what you want replace by what.

On API<11 it may be more complicated to achieve this (I don't know yet how).

Answer (score 3):

You can remove any Element from the page by injecting JavaScript into a WebView. Below is an example of how to inject JavaScrpt into a WebView to remove an element having its id:

```
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

         // Removes element which id = 'mastHead'
         view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                    "(elem = document.getElementById('mastHead')).parentNode.removeChild(elem); " +  
                    "})()");         
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below code to check whether to load it on not. Where webview is the object for WebView.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Toast.makeText(activity,"onPageStarted url :"+url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
                public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Connecting url :"+url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
          public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: but how to use onLoadResource to stop a url from connecting(loading)

Comment: if you dont want to load that resource, then try stop calling super. I am not sure but give a try.

Comment: Even Am searching for this.. will get back to you if i found any solution.

Comment: super.onLoadResource does plain nothing, if you studied Android source, you'd know that. there's nothing to discard here.

Answer (score -3):

The method has 2 params, override it in your webview and discard urls starting with the domain you want to avoid.

Comment: I am really sorry but please can you explain this with a small snippet. That ll be relly helpfull